# in jquery event.preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io, event-handling

I am trying to call jquery's preventDefault() but when I submit the form..it shows the default behaviour and the page gets reloaded.

index.html--

```
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<p>Welcome to the chat app!</p>

<ol id="messages"></ol>

<form id="message-form">
  <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"/><br>
  <button>Send</button>
</form>

</body>
```

script.js---

```
jQuery('#message-form').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
socket.emit('createMessage',{
From:'User',
Text:jQuery('[name=message]').val()
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Is that script wrapped in jQuery.ready? If not since it is in the head it will not find the form because it doesn't exist yet. Also any errors in browser console?

Comment: Nope. It's not wrapped inside jquery.ready method

Comment: So does that fix the problem when it is?

Comment: Thanks man!! that works  fine

Answer (score -1):

If you have a look at the W3C specification, it would seem obvious thing to try to mark your button elements with `type='button'` when you don't want them to submit.

> A button element with no type attribute specified in form represents the same thing as a button element with its type attribute set to "submit"

You should make your button type as "button" and try the code. It should not reload the page.

Comment: No. Then the submit event won't trigger on the form. You need a submit button for that to occur

Comment: It will still trigger, we have a click event attached in the script so that function will be triggered and you can submit the form there.

Comment: Right now since the button acts as a submit type the jQuery('#message-form').on('submit',function(e){..} will not even be in picture since page reloads

Comment: No you are understanding it wrong. A submit button will trigger the submit event that OP is listening to. A `type="button"` also prevents user submitting by hitting enter key on keyboard. the preventDefault() stops the default submit process

Answer (score -1):

Change that button element completely with `<input type="submit" value="Send."/>` and see if that'll work.